# First row is getting selected automatically in Ext.grid.Panel

Tags: extjs

I'm using **ext js** Ext.grid.Panel. And first row is getting selected automatically on Tab/window switch. How do I avoid that ?

EXT JS Version: 6.0.2

selType: 'checkboxmodel'

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [my example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/34uj), by default, the first record is not selected.

Please, create fiddle replayed your problem.

Maybe your application has additional logic for selecting first row.